# Wicket 1.5/6 fragment markup ignored inside body tags - workaround?

Tags: inheritance, wicket, fragment

During migration effort from 1.4x I run into problem with looking up fragment markup.

I use page inheritance and I have my fragment definition on a child page, enclosed by **wicket:extend**. I have **body** tag defined in the parent page which contains . The resulting MarkupStream then contains fragments code inside the body tags.

During markup finding, this whole sections is [skipped](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket-core/6.0.0-beta2/org/apache/wicket/markup/Markup.java#209):

```
if (tag.isOpen() && !tag.hasNoCloseTag() && !(tag instanceof WicketTag) &&
                    !"head".equals(tag.getName()) && !tag.isAutoComponentTag())
                {
                    stream.skipToMatchingCloseTag(tag);
                }
```

I don't understand why skip 90% of elements in MarkupStream. This way all fragments would need to be defined in top page's markup...

Any workaround advice? Conversion to panels not feasible. Possible anti-feature?

Answer (score 1):

Found more information on this (known issue):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4545

http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/MarkupNotFoundException-for-Fragment-and-TransparentWebMarkupContainer-td4619968.html